# How to find the size of smallest and largest bin in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I need to find the the size of bin with maximum and minimum element. I am using `histc` function in MATLAB.

Here is what I am doing,

```
A=[1 2 3 11 22 3 4 55 6 7 2 33 44 5 22]
edges = [10 inf];   
N = histc(A,edges)
```

it gives N=[6,0]; means there are 6 elements having values greater than 10. Now I want to count what is the maximum count in a bin for my condition.

here it should be 2 as there are two instances where we have two integers satisfying my condition `11 22` and `33 44`

How to count it in MATLAB.

Comment: This is not clear. When you say two instances, you mean there are 2 "subarrays"  (int his case of length 2 each) where all the values are bigger than 10?

Comment: BTW you can use `nnz( A > 10 )` to count the number of elements in your vector `A` that meet the condition `> 10`.

Comment: I can count the numbers greater than 10, but I also need to count `length of run` for which numbers are continuously greater than 10. Suppose, there are 12, 1 3, 14, 15 in one run means there are 4 consecutive numbers greater than 10.

Comment: @AnderBiguri two instances means in this array only. You can see that in this array twice I am getting two elements which are greater than 10.

Comment: So what do you want? The length of the biggest >10 consecutive list, or the amount of them?

Comment: First: `B = A > 10`, then you'd have all entries > 10. Now you want to find the length of islands ofn consecutive 1's in B, you can do it like here: https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/86420-find-a-series-of-consecutive-numbers-in-a-vector using `diff`

Comment: This will give you the longest sequence of occurences of numbers > 10: `max(diff([0 (find(~(A>10))) numel(A)+1]) -1)` --> returns 2 in your example. If you set `A=[1 2 3 11 22 3 4 55 6 7 2 33 44 55 5 22]`, then this will yield 3 (33 44 55)

Comment: @AnderBiguri I want to count the max and min number of elements greater than 10 in a particular run. Suppose in an array of size [100X1] I have 12 such runs. The longest run with all values greater than 10 consists of 26 elements while smallest run consist only 3 element.

Comment: hey @tim how to get the smallest sequence of occurences of numbers > 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go;

```
A=[1 2 3 11 22 3 4 55 6 7 2 33 44 5 22]

arr=diff([0 (find(~(A>10))) numel(A)+1]) -1;
arr(find(arr(1,:)==0))=[];

largest=max(arr);   % longest sequence of occurences of numbers > 10
smallest=min(arr);  % smallest sequence of occurences of numbers > 10
```

Cheers!!